# How to uninstall php 7.1

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to install the php driver and for that I first need to unlink the php 7.1 and install the 5.6 but when I try:

brew unlink php71

I get this error message:

Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1

Any suggestion?

Comment: What commands are you using to install/uninstall php?

Comment: PHP 5.6 is beyond end of life. It doesn't get updates any more, not even security updates. Not does 7.0. 7.1 currently only gets security updates and won't next year. You almost certainly should not be trying to install 5.6.

Comment: So do you guys know how to install mongoDB driver? I need it for a corsework and I’ve been strugling with that.

Answer (score 9):

As of macOS 10.14 ("Mojave"), PHP 7.1 is installed as a component of the operating system at `/usr/bin/php`. This installation cannot be removed, but you can install other additional versions of PHP through Homebrew.

[PHP 5.6 reached end-of-life in December 2018](http://php.net/eol.php), and should no longer be used. It is not installable through Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

```
sphp 5.6
```

This will work, if you have installed php through brew. But, I agree with @duskwuff -inactive- that php 5.6 should no longer be used, as suggested by homebrew itself.